# Sort folder names in Python

Tags: python

I would like to sort a list of subfolder names by Python but it does not work in the desired manner.

```
files = ['file_37.png', 'file_8.png', 'file_13.png', 'file_114.png', 'file_115.png']
sorted(files)
```

Output:

```
['file_114.png', 'file_115.png', 'file_13.png', 'file_37.png', 'file_8.png']
```

Apparently, Python is sorting the names in a dictionary form without considering the integer value of the digit after '_'. However, what I want to get is:

```
['file_8.png', 'file_13.png', 'file_37.png','file_114.png', 'file_115.png']
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this desired output in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `key` which is useful for sorting in your own way

`key` will take the function as parameter. What I have done is that I have split the string with `_` and took its second part (index `1`). For example if `file_37.png` is split using `_` then it will give list of `['file', '37.png']`. So using `1` as index will return `37.png`. It is then again split using `.` and I have used the `0` index which returns the file number.

```py
def split_x(x):
  a = x.split('_')[1]
  a = a.split('.')[0]
  return int(a)

files = ['file_37.png', 'file_8.png', 'file_13.png', 'file_114.png', 'file_115.png']
sorted(files, key=split_x)
```

Comment: Thanks, Prakash! Everything is clear now!

Comment: Sorry, Prakash. 
Even though I want to, I cannot cast a vote because I don't have enough reputation yet.